# Dynamically Rerference Cell in Excel

Tags: excel, function, excel-formula

I am trying to reference a cell inside a formula 
for example I have the formula

```
=CORREL(Multiple!$K$11:$K$109,Multiple!K$11:K$109)
```

and I want to reference the K column by using the value K written in another cell

Comment: One option is INDIRECT though it should be used sparingly as it is volatile.

Comment: I tried using it but there seems to be a error  =CORREL(Multiple!$indirect("A20")$11:$K$109,Multiple!K$11:K$109) would you be able to tell me how to correctly use it

Comment: The entire address needs to be inside INDIRECT.

Comment: But how do I use both correl and indirect function together then referencing to the cell a20 for K

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no expierence with `CORREL` Function but I would try something like:

```
=CORREL(INDEX(A11:K109,,CODE(A20)-64),INDEX(A11:K109,,CODE(A20)-64))
```

---

> *" I want to refer from =CORREL(Multiple!$K$11:$K$109,Multiple!K$11:K$109) Instead of K i want to keep changing the column as I go down"*

```
=CORREL(INDEX($11:$109,,ROW(A11)),INDEX($11:$109,,ROW(A11)))
```

And drag down.

Comment: Thought about proposing INDEX... but once OP tries to reference column AA this approach with CODE no longer works (as I'm sure you know :-)

Comment: thanks for the help but I am still not able to figure out how to do it as I am referencing data from another sheet and I just want to change the column name from a cell I want to refer from  =CORREL(Multiple!$K$11:$K$109,Multiple!K$11:K$109)  Instead of K i want to keep changing the column as I go down

Comment: @NikharBajaj - "I want to keep changing the column as I go down" - this sounds like a case for INDEX and ROW.